# MongoDB mongoose add data to array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to add data to an array via a post request with mongoose. I can find the correct data with Model.find(). But I am not sure how to add data to "guests" array on each post request. For example I would like the guests to return something like this (a guest can be added with a post request):

```
guests: [{
    id: 12412,
    naam: 'John',
    email: 'john@doe.com'
  },
  {
    id: 12412,
    naam: 'John',
    email: 'john@doe.com'
  }
]
```

I can find the correct "eventid" (code below) with the dataset but not sure how to add data to "guests".

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var app = express();

var schemaName = new Schema({
  eventid: String,
  evenementnaam: String,
  locatie: String,
  datum: String,
  tijd: String,
  beschrijving: String,
  naam: String,
  email: String,
  telefoon: String,
  image: String,
  time: Number,
  guests: [{
    userid: Number,
    naam: String,
    email: String
  }] // WANT TO ADD TO THIS ARRAY

}, {
  collection: 'evenementen'
});

var Model = mongoose.model('Model', schemaName);

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://db');

app.post('/addguest', function(req, res) {

  req.body.eventid;

  mongoose.connection.on('open', function(err, doc) {
    console.log("connection established");

    mongoose.connection.db.collection('evenementen', function(err, docs) {

      Model.find({
        'eventid': req.body.eventid;
      }, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (result) {
          // ADD GUEST TO GUESTS ARRAY
        } else {
          res.send(JSON.stringify({
            error: 'Error'
          }))

        }
      })


    });
  });
});
```

**Update #1**
The following test is not adding anything to "guests"

```
mongoose.connection.on('open', function (err, doc) {
console.log("connection established");

var newdata = [{
    userid: 21424,
    naam: 'John Test',
    email: 'test@test.com'
}];

mongoose.connection.db.collection('evenementen', function (err, docs) {

    Model.findOne({
        'eventid': 'srA4aqC'
    }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (result) {
            console.log(result);
            Model.update({
                'eventid': 'srA4aqC'
            }, {
                '$push': {
                    'guests': {
                        '$each': newdata
                    }
                }
            })
            console.log('succes');
        } else {
            res.send(JSON.stringify({
                error: 'Error'
            }))

        }
    })


});
});
```

**Update 2**
Need to remove the ' ' from a few elements. Correct code:

```
$push: {
    guests: {
          $each: newdata
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First if your `eventid` is unique the you will need to modify `Model.find()` to `Model.findOne()` which will be much much better and then to update an array field you can use [`$push` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/index.html#up._S_push) like this:

```
if (result) {
    Model.update({'eventid': req.body.eventid}, {'$push': {'guests': result}})
}
```

However, this will do the work if you have one guest value like this:

```
{
    userid: Number,
    naam: String,
    email: String
}
```

but you have `guests` in an array, so you need to use `$each` operator as well:

```
if (result) {
    Model.update({'eventid': req.body.eventid}, {'$push': {'guests': {'$each': result}}})
}
```

Comment: This is not adding new items to the array unfortunately. See #update1.

Comment: The problem was in using the quotation marks. Should have been $push instead of '$push'. Same for guests and $each.